# How can I determine level based on experience?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I simply calculate the level based on an input experience? 
I'm making a "pet chance generator" for a game called runescape. The program asks for your current experience and approximates the level based on the experience value input by the user. Below is the only method I could think of to do this but as you can see there is a wall of text basically copy pasted 40 times. Please help!

I currently have:

```
def calculate_level(xp):
if xp < 368599:
    level = 62
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**2:
    level = 63
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**3:
    level = 64
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**4:
    level = 65
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**5:
    level = 66
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**6:
    level = 67
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**7:
    level = 68
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**8:
    level = 69
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**9:
    level = 70
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**10:
    level = 71
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**11:
    level = 72
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**12:
    level = 73
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**13:
    level = 74
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**14:
    level = 75
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**15:
    level = 76
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**16:
    level = 77
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**17:
    level = 78
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**18:
    level = 79
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**19:
    level = 80
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**20:
    level = 81
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**21:
    level = 82
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**22:
    level = 83
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**23:
    level = 84
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**24:
    level = 85
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**25:
    level = 86
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**26:
    level = 87
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**27:
    level = 88
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**28:
    level = 89
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**29:
    level = 90
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**30:
    level = 91
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**31:
    level = 92
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**32:
    level = 93
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**33:
    level = 94
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**34:
    level = 95
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**35:
    level = 96
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**36:
    level = 97
elif xp < 368599 * 1.101141**37:
    level = 98
else:
    level = 99
return level
```

Comment: Maybe you could plot all these points on a graph and see if some nice function emerge.

Comment: hehehehe there is a clear pattern already, but why does it start at 62?

Comment: If you're suggesting that the exponent and level could both be variables because they change by one each line then I already thought of that but I don't know how to translate it to python. It starts at 62 because i was only calculating the chances for catching one type of fish which requires a level of 62

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smells like logarithm..

```
import math

def xp_to_level(xp):
    return math.ceil(math.log(xp/368599, 1.101141)) + 61
```

Usage:

```
>>> xp_to_level(123456)
50
```

Comment: Whoa that's smart.. Too bad logarithms were always my weakest area in math. so math.log(xp/368599, 1.101141) takes the log of base 1.101141 of xp/368599?

Comment: @qazwsx598 Correct! Since the logarithm is the inverse of exponentiation, and you're essentially trying to "undo" an exponentiation.

Comment: @AntonvBR How does your question differ in functionality (other than being an O(n) lookup instead of O(1))?

Comment: @AntonvBR I don't think they need a way to go from level to xp, and even then, the inverted formula is easier and asymptotically faster than using a file and an OrderedDict: `def level_to_xp(level): return 368599 * 1.101141**(level-61)`

Comment: Nvm, As I put earlier I think you answered this perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well one bad way you can simplify this is this

```
def calculate_level(xp):
    if xp < 368599:
        return 62
    for i in reversed(range(63, 99)):
        if xp > 368599 * 1.101141**(i - 62):
            return i
```

But the other better thing to do is to work out a more mathematical definition of this problem and just figure out the direct function.

I think it would be something along the lines of

```
level = floor(log_1.101141(xp / 368599) +62)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is one way to do it (not complete solution but an example)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import io

# Put your levels in a csvfile

data = '''\
62,144815767.41229948
63,159462585.01260683
64,175590796.3918269
65,193350231.1981527
66,212905873.000225
67,234439391.96980074
68,258150832.58147836
69,284260472.00806165
70,313010866.47588897
71,344669104.59058684'''

file = io.StringIO(data)

# Read file to dictionary
L = OrderedDict((int(i.split(',')[0]),float(i.split(',')[1])) for i in file.read().split('\n'))

experience = 450000

# Now to the code
current_lvl = next(k for k,v in L.items() if v > experience)
```

Returns `62`. Now that you have a dictionary you can do things like:

Calculate the exp needed for next level like this:

```
L.get(current_lvl+1)-experience
```

Returns `159012585.01260683`